# Is there any way to project the size of intersection between two numerical ranges using mongo language?

Tags: mongodb

My sample data:

```
db.test.insert([{range:[1, 8]},
{range:[4, 8]},
{range:[1,9]},
{range:[3, 5]}])
```

And I have a variable:

```
query = [2, 5]
```

I want to do something like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
{$project:{overlap: {$IntersectionOfRanges:["$range", query]} }},
...
```

So that it projects 3 for 1st doc, 1 for 2nd, 3 for 3rd and 2 for 4th. Of course, this "$IntersectionOfRanges" function is completely made up. The only solution in mongo I can think of is to include the whole sequence of integers in an array (e.g., [1, 5] turns into [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) and then use $SetIntersection. Unfortunately, some of the ranges are much longer than those in the sample, I cannot afford to keep arrays of 100 or so numbers in the database. Is this even accomplishable?

Comment: AFAICT, your data-model does not fit well with the aggregation framework. Have you the choice to change it from `{range:[1, 8]}` to `{range:{from:1, to:8}}` ? Is using map-reduce an option ?

Comment: Thanks.
Yes I can restructure data in any way.
Map-reduce is definitely an option if it can solve the problem, although aggregation is preferred :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve that issue, you basically have to implement [*interval trichotomy*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Cij_VTAAzWEC&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187) using the aggregation framework. Things are not as hard as it sounds. But due to some limitation in MongoDB expression syntax, using an array like you suggested first would make things really hard.

But, as you explained in a comment, restructuring your schema is an option. So I would go toward that instead:

```
db.test.insert([
  {range:{from:1, to:8}},
  {range:{from:4, to:8}},
  {range:{from:1, to:9}},
  {range:{from:3, to:5}},
])
```

With that new model, you can find range intersection using that simple aggregation pipeline:

```
query = [2, 5]

db.test.aggregate([
  {$project: {
     from: {$cond: [{$gt: ["$range.from", query[0]]}, "$range.from", query[0]]},
     to: {$cond: [{$lt: ["$range.to", query[1]]}, "$range.to", query[1]]},
  }}
])
```

Now, `from` is the minimum between the document `range.from` field and the start of the target range. `to` is the maximum between the document `range.to` field and the end of the target range. So, at this point:

- When `to` is lower than `from`, there was *no* intersection between the two ranges<sup>1</sup>;
- Otherwise, your intersection is the range between `from` and `to` (possibly limited to a single value)

Given the data set on top on this answer, the above aggregation pipeline (with an extra step to add the "width" of the range) will produce:

```
> query = [2, 5]
> db.test.aggregate([
      {$project: {
         from: {$cond: [{$gt: ["$range.from", query[0]]}, "$range.from", query[0]]},
         to: {$cond: [{$lt: ["$range.to", query[1]]}, "$range.to", query[1]]},
      }},
      {$project: { width: { $subtract: [ "$to", "$from" ]},
                   from: 1,
                   to: 1,
      }}
    ])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "from" : 2, "to" : 5, "width" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "from" : 4, "to" : 5, "width" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "from" : 2, "to" : 5, "width" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "from" : 3, "to" : 5, "width" : 2 }
```

And, using a different range:

```
> query = [8, 10]
> db.test.aggregate([
...   {$project: {
...      from: {$cond: [{$gt: ["$range.from", query[0]]}, "$range.from", query[0]]},
...      to: {$cond: [{$lt: ["$range.to", query[1]]}, "$range.to", query[1]]},
...   }}
... ])

{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "from" : 8, "to" : 8, "width" : 0 } // single point
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "from" : 8, "to" : 8, "width" : 0 } // single point
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "from" : 8, "to" : 9, "width" : 1 } // range intersection
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "from" : 8, "to" : 5, "width" : -3 } // NO intersection
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>You can go even further in your analysis, as if `from > to` and `from = query[0]` (resp. `to = query[1]`) you know that the document range was *below* (resp. *above*) the target range.</sub>